# Corona/Lua/Android: Why does the input field for a textField maximize and cover half the screen on my Nexus 5?

Tags: android, coronasdk, textfield

I'm trying to make a textField that accepts input. My problem is, that when a user taps a textField, the input field is maximized so that it covers half the background image (the keyboard covering the other half).
The picture below shows what the background image looks like before the user taps one of the five textFields (the grey bars).

[image]

The image below and to the left shows what currently happens when I tap a textField: the input field is enlarged and completely covers the background image. What I WANT to happen, however, is what I've tried to show below and to the right: the textField is focused and the user can start writing while the background is still visible.

[image]

The app works fine on my Samsung Galaxy tablet, but for some reason I have this issue on my Nexus 5 phone only. The phone has plenty of other apps where the example to the right is what happens, so I at least know that it's possible. How do you do it?

(Was unable to find a tag for the Nexus 5)

Comment: This problem has absolutely nothing to do with Lua. That tag should probably be removed.

Comment: Can you show the code you tried to male it work?

Answer (score 1):

This is a common problem. See http://forums.coronalabs.com/topic/36320-keyboard-covers-my-textfield-when-placed-on-botton-of-the-screen/ for some ideas. Some devs create their own virtual kb, see eg https://developer.coronalabs.com/category/tags/keyboard for some libs to help with this.

Answer (score 0):

This is the ExtractEditText UI; you just need to add a flag to disable it. On your `EditText`, set the attribute:

```
android:imeOptions="flagNoExtractUi"
```

Comment: I tried this:
if ( event.phase == "editing") then
android:imeOptions="flagNoExtractUi"
  end
But it didn't work. Threw the error "111.lua:86: function arguments expected near '='"